# UIBackgroundTask not ending

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibackgroundtask

I am using UIBackgroundtaskIdentifier to create background task of uploading images to server.

```
NSLog(@"Time left = %.1f seconds", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
```

When I take the application in to background, it show that applicaiton have 179 seconds to run in background. I log the server responses as it uploads that images one by one.

```
    [[DataCoordinator sharedInstance] setBackgroundTask:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"No background task should run now.");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:[[DataCoordinator sharedInstance] backgroundTask]];
        [[DataCoordinator sharedInstance] setBackgroundTask:UIBackgroundTaskInvalid];
    }]];
```

The strange thing happening here is that, after the time provided by iOS for my application to run in background is over still the upload doesn't stops. Suppose I tried uploading 33 images, and when 179 seconds got complete application was successful uploading only 9 out of 33 images. But the process doesn't stop. And application keep uploading the remaining pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on `backgroundTimeRemaining`.
Apple says that when you run the app on the background the app may by killed:

> This property contains the amount of time the app has to run in the
>   background before it may be forcibly killed by the system.

In reality you can have a few second or 5 minutes, it depends on many thing like battery life, memory usage, etc.
You have to program the app to do right thing no matter what backgroundTimeRemaining is showing.